# Can you explain me better coroutine and why i am having this output

Tags: lua, coroutine

Here is my logic:

```
local get_package = coroutine.create(function(packageName)
    local url = "https://registry.npmjs.org/" .. packageName .. "/latest"
    local cmd = "curl -s '" .. url .. '\' | grep -Po \'(?<="version":")[^"]*\''
    local handle = io.popen(cmd)
    if handle then
        local version = handle:read("*line")
        handle:close()
        return version
    end
end)

local ps = { "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb", "lodash", "lodash" }

for _, p in ipairs(ps) do
    print(p)
    local success, result = coroutine.resume(get_package, p)
    if success then
        print(tostring(result))
    else
        print("error:" .. tostring(result))
        break
    end
end
```

Output:

```
 @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb
 3.293.0
 lodash
 error:cannot resume dead coroutine
```

How to fix that? I tried to `coroutine.yield` instead of returning the result same issue.

Comment: When the function terminates, the coroutine becomes "dead".  You may invoke `coroutine.yield` in a loop to process multiple inputs and return mutliple outputs before exiting the function.

Comment: thanks @ESkri  i changed my logic to the one below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a misunderstood of `coroutine`

I achieved what i would like to do by changing the logic to this:

```
Hello = coroutine.create(function(ps)
    for _, p in ipairs(ps) do
        local url = "https://registry.npmjs.org/" .. p .. "/latest"
        local cmd = "curl -s '" .. url .. '\' | grep -Po \'(?<="version":")[^"]*\''
        local handle = io.popen(cmd)
        if handle then
            local version = handle:read("*line")
            handle:close()
            if version ~= nil then
                coroutine.yield(version)
            end
        end
    end
end)

local ps = { "react", "vue", "angular" }
for i = 1, 3, 1 do
    print(i)
    print(coroutine.resume(Hello, ps))
    print("done")
end
```